# angular bootstrap scrolling tabs

Tags: angularjs, scroll, tabs

Guys I am beginner in AngularJs and javascript.
In my project, I am using this plugin https://github.com/mikejacobson/angular-bootstrap-scrolling-tabs
but I am facing error and I am not able to find the root cause even after spending too much time.
Here's my HTML code -

```
<div class="scrolling-tabs-container" ng-controller="MainController as main">
<div scrolling-tabs-wrapper>
<tabset ng-show="main.tabs.length" style="z-index: 50px;"> 
<tab ng-repeat="t in main.tabs" active="t.active" class="tabclass">
<tab-heading style="padding: 5px">{{t.title}}
<a ng-click="removeTab($index)" href=''>
<i class="selected-tab"></i>
<i class="icon-remove"></i>
</a>
</tab-heading>
<div ng-bind-html='to_trusted(t.content)'></div>
</tab>
</tabset>
</div>  
</div>
```

I have included the required javascript files and css files but I am facing this error when I am trying to click left scroll arrow-

```
TypeError: stc.$leftScrollArrow.add is not a function
at ElementsHandler.p.setElementReferences (scrolling-tabs.js:231)
at ElementsHandler.p.initElements (scrolling-tabs.js:170)
at __initTabsAfterTimeout (scrolling-tabs.js:525)
at angular-1.3.15.min.js:16298
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular-1.3.15.min.js:4924)
at angular-1.3.15.min.js:5312(anonymous function) @ angular-1.3.15.min.js:11654
```

Has someone used this plugin? Can someone help me understanding this issue? Please help.

Comment: I loaded Jquery before AngularJS and the error is gone.

Comment: There is another plugin which is also good for implementing scrolling tabs if you are using UIBootstrap tabs. here is the link - https://github.com/VersifitTechnologies/angular-ui-tab-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amarpreet, make sure jQuery is loaded before angular, as the [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mikejacobson/angular-bootstrap-scrolling-tabs/issues/3)
says

Comment: Thanks AlexWS. I loaded Jquery before AngularJS and the error is gone. Thanks!